# Convert to decimal arguments

Tags: python-3.x

Two integers as command line arguments where the first is expressed to the base of the second. How to I do this

```
enter code here import sys
                a = int(sys.argv[1])
                b = int(sys.argv[2])
```

do I use a binary search? There question on here that convert to decimal but how to I take the arguments base by the second eg 110 2 is 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this conversion:

```
a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
number = int(a, base=int(b))
```

As specified in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

> Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or return 0 if no arguments are given. If x is a number, return x.**int**(). For floating point numbers, this truncates towards zero.
>   If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string, bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix base.

Comment: got the error TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base. Fxed it but what was this error mean?

Comment: @DeclanLunney fixed. You need to remove the first casts. I've updated my answer.

Comment: when i removed int from int(sys.argv[1]) it works. I am just wondering why it doesnt work if int is here?

Comment: @DeclanLunney as the documentation reads: "If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string, bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix base."